# Using one views gsp in another views gsp

Tags: grails, groovy, render, gsp

So my question is, hopefully, very simple.

I have two different domains with corresponding controllers/view folders etc.

I want to call the second _form.gsp from the first _form.gsp (within a g:each as there will be multiple things to display) and pass in the relevant data for the second _form.gsp to render from, how do I do that?

I know I can use g:render template = "myotherForm" but I don't know how to point it to another view folder or how to pass in the details...

Thanks in advance and let me know if more information is required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `<g:render` is the right tool. By default, for `template="myOtherTempalte"` it looks for tempalte in current directory, but you could pass full path, if it's from another controller. Like `template="/forms/myOtherTemplate"`. And use `model=""` to pass parameters, same as inside controller:

```
<g:each in="${things}" var="x">
  <g:render template="/forms/myOtherTemplate" model="${thing: x}"/>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Thanks Igor that works a treat.  Can I, for the model, just give it the id field and number of the object I want it to load or do I have to feed everything in?

Comment: you could put into model anything required by included template, depends on template only

Answer (score 3):

You can [Refer this](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#gsp)

Grails uses the convention of placing `underscore` before the name of a view to identify it as a template.

Example `grails-app/views/book/_bookTemplate.gsp:`

```
<div class="book" id="${book?.id}">
   <div>Title: ${book?.title}</div>
   <div>Author: ${book?.author?.name}</div>
</div>
```

Then use render tag

```
<g:render template="bookTemplate" model="[book: myBook]" />
```

Comment: Thanks- I didn't know about the underscore convention and it was screwing me up